# Visualizing PCA transformed data

Tags: python, machine-learning, k-means, pca, unsupervised-learning

I have a dataset on which I want to do clustering with k-means.
As a prior task I run PCA on this data and identified two components that are representing almost 90% of the information of my dataset.
I want to visualize these two components in order to draw some insight.

```
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
data_trans = pca.fit_transform(data)
plt.scatter(data_trans[:, 0], data_trans[:, 1])
```

[image]

Next I try to visualize the same transformed data but from the transposed matrix

```
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
data_trans = pca.fit_transform(data.T)
plt.scatter(data_trans[:, 0], data_trans[:, 1])
```

[image]

Does the last plot is an indication of potentially 6 clusters in my data ?
What conclusion can I draw from these two drawing, if any?

Comment: Variance is not information. Addhigh-variance random attributes and they will drown your informarion. Nothing saves you from having to understand your data...

Answer (score 1):

The 6 points you see are not clusters.

They are your input dimensions.

Because you used the transposed matrix.

Judging feom above plots, I doubt that clustering will find anything meaningful there. Outliers, and one big blob, is what the plot contains.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. From there how can I isolate the outliers and translate them to original data? An example of such "translation" will be very useful.

Comment: Just select them by their values and  ID, instead of translating them back. PCA as used here is lossy. But I don't think the outliers are that helpful either, they may just be artifacts.